# inode based file system, What is the maximum size of a file in the file system

Tags: files, filesystems, inode, size

could someone explain how to tackle this questions?

```
1. **What is the maximum size of a file that could be handled by single indirect and double indirect?**

Block size is 2K
Address size is 4 Bytes
12 slots for direct disk blocks
One slot each for single indirect and double indirect.
```

_

```
2. **What is the maximum size of a file that could be handled by single indirect and double indirect?**


Block size is 4096 bytes can contain 1024 block references.
12 slots for direct disk blocks
One slot each for single indirect and double indirect.
```

my attampt:

```
1.
Block size is 2K = 2**11 
Address size is 4 Bytes = 2**2 
in one block are (2**11/2**2)= 2**9 pointers 

12 slots for direct disk blocks
One slot each for single indirect = 2**9
and double indirect. = 2**18

Maximum file size 
( 12 + 2**9 + 2**18 ) * 2**11 = 2**29 ~ 536 MB
```

_

```
2.
Block size is 4096 bytes can contain 1024 block references

12 slots for direct disk blocks
One slot each for single indirect = 1024 = 2**10
and double indirect. = 1024**2 = 2**20

Maximum file size 
( 12 + 2**10 + 2**20 ) * 2**12 = 2**32
( 12 + 1024 + 1024**2 ) * 4096 = ~ 4GB
```

Still i am not sure if this is correct and where i am mistaken

my sources are:

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742163/maximum-file-size-given-a-particular-inode-structure

-https://cis.temple.edu/~ingargio/cis307/readings/stable.html

-https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~kwebb/cs45/s18/09-File_Systems.pdf

Comment: Looks to make sense to me. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/dynamic.html#direct-indirect-block-addressing also has a description of the indirect block addressing, and numbers for 4096 B blocks. They seem to match the ones you have here.